# How to extract JSP forEach index to Controller on POST/DELETE?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a jsp table with dynamically created rows - each row is binded to DAO. Each row also has a button that is supposed to provide availability to delete that DAO from DB and of course from the table itself.

My question is, how can I inform controller which exactly DAO was called to be deleted?

My idea was to extract varStatus index to controller and find it with @ModelAttribute ("games") somehow, but honestly I don't know how to pass this index up to controller. I know model is generated by controller and passed  to JSP which extracts the data from the model and renders it, but what I'm doing here is obviously a POST/DELETE method.

My Controller mapping for that jsp:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/deleteGame", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getDeleteGame (ModelMap model) {
    List<Game> myGames = gamesService.fetchById();
    model.addAttribute("games", myGames);
    return "deleteGame";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/deleteGame", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String postDeleteGame (ModelMap model) {
    return "deleteGame";
}
```

And here is my ref JSP table:

```
<div class="table-responsive" id="tableWithBg">
                    <table class = "table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="col-md-2">TITLE</th>
                                <th class="col-md-2">TYPE</th>
                                <th class="col-md-2">MODE</th>
                                <th class="col-md-2">PRODUCER</th>
                                <th class="col-md-3">OPINION</th>
                                <th class="col-md-1">DELETE</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <c:forEach items="${games}" var="game" varStatus="loopIndex">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>${game.title}</td>
                                    <td>${game.type}</td>   
                                    <td>${game.mode}</td>
                                    <td>${game.producent}</td>
                                    <td>${game.opinion}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" action="delete" onclick="getCategoryIndex(${loopIndex.index})" class="btn btn-danger">
                                            <strong>X</strong>
                                        </button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </c:forEach>                                                            
                        </tbody>
                    </table>                
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, add common class(like class="js-delete-game") to all your delete button to check which button is triggered.
`data-game-id="${game.id}"` is game's unique id (supposing that your unique id is id) to remove appropriate game.

```
<button data-game-id="${game.id}" type="button" class="js-delete-game" id="js-delete-game${game.id}">
  <strong>X</strong>
</button>
```

An event handler to check which button is clicked and ajax method to remove your game.

```
//<table id="game-list">
$("#game-list").on('click','.js-delete-game',function(event){
    var id = $(event.target).data('gameId'); //data-game-id Get your unique game ID from the clicked button.
    var data = JSON.stringify({"id":id});
    var rowId= "#"+event.target.id; //get button id from clicked button and create selector
    $.ajax({
    type : "DELETE",
    url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteGame",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data : data,
    success: function(data){
       //remove row deleted on page without refreshing.
       $(rowId).closest('tr').remove();
    }
    });
});
```

Finally change your mapping method as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteGame" , method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseBody
public void deleteGameById(@RequestBody Map<String, String> id) {
  //your logic maybe different  
  gamesService.remove(id.get("id")); 
}
```

Briefly, if you click the delete button, the game's unique id will send to server. Now you can get the id on server-side and delete the game by id.